# Crop big images in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, crop

I'm displaying big images in my app and want to crop them. The user can rotate and scale the images and select a region he wants to crop.

How can I crop out a 10000x10000 region, starting at point `(1000, 1000)` for example from a 20000x20000 image? For loading parts of an image I would use `BitmapRegionDecoder` but I don't know how to combine them to a new image again. Any ideas?

Rotation is another problem, this won't work with the `BitmapRegionDecoder` , but I would already be glad to have a solution without rotation...

I would need a memory friendly way that is more than just following:

```
Bitmap bitmap = loadFullBitmapIntoMemory();
Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 1000, 1000, 10000, 10000);
```

I want to avoid to load the full image into memory...

Comment: Since1 pixel is 1 byte, what you are trying to do will need 400MB in memory for an image of 20000x20000 just to be loaded.

Comment: Not if I load tiles of the image only and somehow could combine those tiles afterwards again...